# Nginx - Passenger - Rails 3.2 not responding

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

I am struggeling to get my rails 3.2 app running on a nginx - passenger - ruby 1.9.3 setup.

here is what I already did:

```
installed passenger gem
installed rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

I added this to my nginx conf at /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_spawn_method smart;
  rails_env staging;
  root /var/rails/current/public;
}
```

I deployed via Capistrano and everything seems to be deployed correctly.
I had some issues (database.yml couldn't be found) on first try and the passenger exception page appeared so I guess passenger is running.

Passenger exception page also shows up if there is an error within a model so passenger seems to have access to all of the code.

After I fixed this it seems like the Rails app is not booting up. The staging.log stays empty and calls to my domain end up with a `HTTP 504` error after a few minutes.

**Static error pages within the rails public directory like
http://mydomain.com/500.html**
are served without problems.

What can be the reason for this behavior? Are there passenger / nginx log files I can check?

Update: I am running all this on a EC2 Ubuntu instance - maybe this is important.

Thanks!

NOTE: this is a direct duplicate of [this question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10387563). I am new to serverfault but i guess this is the better place for this question - so feel free to vote for delete on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same thing as i did on Ubuntu 12.04 now on **Ubuntu 11.10 and it works without problems**. Maybe someone discovers the same problem and knows how to solve it unter Ubuntu 12.04!